# How can I verify a CVE is applied to tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat7

How can I verify a particular CVE is applied to a current installed Tomcat version? For ex: verify CVE-2016-3092 for Tomcat 7.0.70.B

Answer (score 1):

7.0.70.B is not an Apache Tomcat version number. That looks like a version number for a tc Runtime, part of Pivotal's tc Server product. If you have questions about security fixes for tc Server and the information is not in the documentation, you'll  need to contact Pivotal support.